# Using jquery to displaying query results in a form

Tags: jquery

A friend recently introduced me to jquery and now I'd like to use it rewrite and develop a inventory web application.

My original app consisted of a simple web page that required you to enter an id number and click a button.  The id number is passed to a php file via the post method. The php file queries a database and displays the results in a table.

I created a HTML form that I would like to use update, enter new records, and display query results based on the button pressed.

At this time I want to display query results.

I have figured out how to use jquery to display the results of a query in a div at the bottom of my form.  what I need help with is how if display the results in given location of the form.

Here is a real simple example of what I want:

### HTML

```
<html>  
< head>  
< title>JQuery test< /title>  
< /head>  
< body>  
< form>  
< table>  
< tr>< th>Equipment ID< /th>  
< td>< input type="text name="eqid" id="eqid" />< /td>  
< th>Manufacturer< /th>  
< td>< input type="text name="manuf" id="manuf" />< /td>  
< th>Model< /th>  
< td>< input type="text name="model" id="model" />< /td>< tr>  
< /table>  
< div id=output> < /div>  
< /form>  
< /body>  
< /html>
```

### JQUERY

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function()  
{  
  var data = $('form:first').serialize();  
   $.ajax(  
   {  
    url:"passdata.php",   
    type: "POST",  
    data:data,  
    success:function(data)  
    {  
       $("#output").html(data);  
    } //end success  
   }); // end ajax  
});  // end click
```

---

This what I'm using on my php file

### PHP

```
<?php
    $eqid = $_POST['eqid'];  
    $manuf = 'Apple';  
    $model ='IPAD 2';  

    echo "<table border=0><tr>";
    echo "<th align ='left'>Manufacturer</th><td><input name='manuf' id='manuf' type='text' size='10' value=" . $manuf . "></td></tr>";  
    echo "<tr><th align ='left'>Surveyed by</th><td><input name='model' id='model' type='text' value=". $model . "></td></tr></total>";  
?php>
```

---

I would like the results of the query (manufacture and model) to be displayed in the appropriate location of the form in the example above.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: What is the problem? You seem to have been able to establish all steps you require...? So try to explain better what goes wrong or what errors you get.

Comment: In the example I posted, I want the manufacturer value and model value of the query result show up next o the respective label in the html form

Comment: I assume that 'Apple' and Ipad 2' are place-holders for values that come from a database of some sort? What about all the other information in that table? Do you want the table to display as well? Your question is only asking how to put values in a form, what all do you want displayed on the page when you are done?

Comment: As an aside, that php is returning html with the same format (read: IDs) as your original table. If you want to do that you should probably destroy the old table and replace it. Otherwise you have duplicated IDs...

Comment: Yes to the Apple and IPAD 2...  I wanted to keep it simple so I could understand how to use ajax with jquery... The html in the php file was just me seeing how $("#output").html(data); worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passdata.php needs to do your database querying then return the data. JSON is a nice way of doing this.

```
<?php
$iteminfo = array('id' => $id, 'manuf' => $manuf, 'model' => $model);

echo json_encode($iteminfo);
?>
```

your ajax call then needs to take this data and populate your form.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function()  
{  
  var data = $('form:first').serialize();  
   $.ajax(  
   {  
    url:"passdata.php",   
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data:data, 
    success:function(data)  
    {  
       $("eqid").val(data.id); 
       $("manuf").val(data.manuf);
       $("model").val(data.model);      
    } //end success  
   }); // end ajax  
});  // end click
```

Of course if you're using the same form for all CRUD operations, your php is going to have to be just as sneaky as your javascript. You sure this is a good idea for you?

Comment: I've added the php script... Not sure if it's a good idea yet... will know once I get more start work on the other parts...

Comment: Your php script is outputting a string of html. Do you want to display that html as well? If you want to give your phone number to a friend it isn't necessary to write it on scented parchment just to pass the information.

Comment: Sinetheta:  No I don't need to display the results in html as well.  I only want to display the results of the query next the appropriate lablel...

Comment: Hey Sinetheta.... I followed your example but no luck... the value is not displaying..... when I use $("#output").html(data); it shows the array with the all the key/value pairs so the data is being in the array.

Comment: my "approach" would have needed a lot more supporting code, the php I included was just the final step to serialize the data. It was a replacement for the html you are currently outputting, not a fix. You either have to commit to sending back HTML and doing something with it, or sending back raw data.

Comment: The reason I couldn't provide a solution for just "moving" your returned HTML into the form is that you have invalidated your page by duplicating IDs. If you want to stick with html then change the output of passdata.php so that you aren't returning elements with IDs that already exist.

Comment: Ok, I am beginning to understand what you're saying... I like would like to use your JSON suggestion to accomplish what I want. Here is a link to my test spec: http://tobagoborn.com/test/jquery/ if you click on the button you will see the json array... Now I need to figure out the supporting code for what you wrote.

Comment: Sinetheta... I was able to display the data in the form fields using your suggestions and help!! Thanks